# React Native - collect feedback from testers via Firebase. Cannot find symbol

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I've followed these instructions on how to collect in-app feedback from testers via Firebase - https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-distribution/android/distribute-cli?hl=en&authuser=0

However, after following all the steps the app no longer builds for Android - it fails with this error -

```java
[...]/app/MainActivity.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
  FirebaseAppDistribution firebaseAppDistribution = FirebaseAppDistribution.getInstance();
```

I can't figure out where I've gone wrong though. Can anyone advise?